# Collision symmetry and measuring the asymmetry in the Drell-Yan process

Tags: particle-physics, collision, quarks, large-hadron-collider

I saw a talk the other day about an asymmetry in the [Drell-Yan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drell%E2%80%93Yan_process) process caused by [CP-violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation):

[image]

Apparently one way this can be measured ([ATLAS](http://atlas.ch/) is doing this) is to collide protons and observe the distribution of the Collins-Soper polar angle $\cos\theta^*$, defined in the Collins-Soper frame (I'm afraid I'm not exactly clear on how this frame is defined - this is probably part of my problem - but I do have a diagram):

[image]

The asymmetry is apparent as an uneven distribution of forward $\cos\theta^*>0$ (left) and backward $\cos\theta^*<0$ (right) events:

[image]

This seems straightforward enough to measure; just see which way the leptons come out. But this assumes you know which way the quark and anti-quark came in! As I understand it, the collision is between a "valence quark" in one proton and a "sea anti-quark" (some kind of virtual anti-quark?) in the other proton. But the beam is just a bunch of protons colliding, so how can we know which proton contributed a quark to the collision, and which contributed an anti-quark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About half of the proton's momentum is carried by the valence quarks (uud) and the rest is spread around many gluons and many sea-quarks ($q\bar{q}$ pairs).

In the Drell-Yan process, it is assumed that the colliding quark is a valence quark and the anti-quark must be a sea quark. We are colliding a highly energetic quark with a low energy anti-quark. This leads to a boost with respect to the colliding axis. The direction of this boost is the direction of the quark. This allows us to infer from which proton the quark came from, and same for the anti-quark.